# HTML Coloring Help?

Tags: html, tags

I really need help :)
I have to put multiple words in a line, each with a different color, I tried wrapping each word in a `<div> </div>` and styling, but it seems it makes a new line between words.

Comment: give each word "display:inline;" style, either individually or in a CSS section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<span>`.

`<div>`s are used for block-level elements. `<span>` is used for inline elements, such as text enclosed in a `<p>` element.

Further reading: [Span and div](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<div>` is a block element. Try `<span>` (an inline element) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Span tag instead, like

```
This <span style="color:red;">text</span> is red, but <span style="color:blue;">THIS</span> text is blue!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span> </span>` It is what it is mean to.

Then you can set css classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
   <head>
       <title>My web</title>
       <style type="text/css">
           yellow {
           color: yellow;
 }
        </style>
   </head>

   <body>

        Span is not at the <span class="yellow">yellow level</span>. 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about CSS, sorry, is their any other way?

Comment: How are you giving the words their colors? with something like <div style="color:red;">redword</div>, correct? So change every "div" to be "span".

Comment: you declare in the HTML a css tag, then declare like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block-level element. This means you either need to apply a `display: inline` style to it or better yet, use an inline tag such as `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

use 
    `<span>Text Here</span>`
And style it in your css.